# How can I draw isometric dot paper with a scale size of 1cm with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to put 1cm isometric dot paper into an exercise of the exam for my class, so my students can draw on.
My apologies for no MWE. I haven't got a clue where to start. See image

[image]

Comment: When you say 1cm, is that the vertical or horizontal difference between two dots? Or is 1cm the vertical distance as well as the distance to the above left and above right dot?

Comment: In isometry, the dot distances (let's call it the unit vectors) along the 30 deg lines and the vertical lines are the same. I guess it is this distance OP wants to be 1 cm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating a dotted paper pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162403/creating-a-dotted-paper-pdf) Related enough to get you started but not isometric dots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isometric dots can easily be created by modifying the `x` and `y` coordinates and then putting dots on a grid. However we would need to clip the result, because we basically rotated the coordinate system. The scale has to be adopted to your liking, as I asked how the `1cm` shall be defined and now used the assumption of @AlexG.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.86cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.86cm,0.5cm)}]
\clip (0,12.5) rectangle (25,12.5);
\foreach \x in {0,...,25}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,25}
    {
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit after the comments of Jon

I took some measurements with Adobe Acrobat in the PDF created from the code above and this is the result:
[image]

So which measurement needs to be 1cm, if you take this image as a reference?
[image]

### The isometric A4-paper

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={0.23cm 0.25cm}]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.86cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.86cm,0.5cm)}]
\clip (0,25.5) rectangle (37.5,29);
\foreach \x in {0,...,50}
\foreach \y in {0,...,50}
{
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted 1 cm going across and down, also how did you know to use those particular coordinates (0.86cm. 05cm)?

Comment: @Jon This is due to trigonometry: sin(60°) = 0.866 and cos(60°) = 0.5.

Comment: @Jon AJ explained it already, it is based on the isometric projection. I have seen you tried to edit my answer instead of adding a comment, I will follow up on that later. Basically to not cut between dots, use a coordinate that doesn‘t cut through, so x.5 helps.

Comment: TobiBS,  I only understood your answer when I removed the clip I got a "rhombus" with the corners at (0,0), (0,25), (25,25), (25,0), then I \clip (0,16.5) rectangle (25,8.5); this gave me the top 10 cm for the top of my page, which I wanted, but when I print the whole page I do get isometric paper but 2 cm in length going across and down.I will wait for your follow up and then vote as solved for me

Comment: @Jon Exactly, this is what you would do, basically the new definitions for x and y are defining a new coordinate system which is defined by new vectors. However I still don't get which measurement you want to be 1cm. Please see my edit of the answer, it shows an actual measurement from Adobe Acrobat. So which measurement do you want to change? Please indicate red, green or blue as in my second additional image.

Comment: TobiBS, your dimensions are exactly the same as the Isometric Dot Paper 1 cm from Printerest, which is what I require. When I print using your code the red line is 13 mm dots apart the blue is 23 mm, and the green is also 13 mm dots apart, and its in landscape not portrait, not sure it that means anything. I am using Windows 8.1, Texstudio and Adobe DC, for printing.

Comment: @Jon it seems you let Adobe or your printer scale the printout. So as long as you use the standalone package, the page size will be arbitrary. Use the setting none, as in this screenshot: https://www.cadzation.com/help/acroplot/drex_pro_troubleshooting_printingfromadobe2_custom.png or read the complete article: https://www.cadzation.com/help/acroplot/pro_troubleshooting_printingfromadobe2.htm
Alternatively I can change my solution to be printed on A4 paper if you want.

Comment: You are a genius, first I printed the compiled file using SumatraPDF and it printed correctly, but in landscape, then I used Adobe DC using your suggestion it  is"actual size" in Adobe DC, and it printed correctly, Can you change your solution to A4? I have learnt so much from this question.

Comment: @Jon No I'm not, but I made the same mistakes a long time ago. ;-) I added another section of code to produce a page which is `29.7cm x 21cm`, be aware however that you still need to select "actual size", otherwise most printers reduce the size to the printable area.

Comment: @Jon **A4**?, see [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559660) ;-)

Answer (score 9):

### Update 2: new coordinate system defined with pgfkeys

Coordinates are given in the same style as the native implicit coordinates of tikz, i.e. 3 numbers separated by commas. They are prefixed by `iso cs:` as for example: `(iso cs:0,1,7)`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfkeys{/isometrique/.cd,
      coordonnee/.code args={#1,#2,#3}
        {
            \def\myx{#1}
            \def\myy{#2}
            \def\myz{#3}
        }
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{isometric}
{
    \pgfkeys{/isometrique/.cd,
              coordonnee={#1}}
    \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointxyz{0}{\myz}{0}}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolarxy{-30}{\myx}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{30}{\myy}}}
}
\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{iso}{isometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Triangle[angle=45:4pt 3]}]

\newcommand{\nbx}{11}%<--number of point on one row
\newcommand{\nby}{9}%<-- number of point on one column

\foreach \j in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nby-1} {
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nbx-1} 
  {\fill[black](90:\j)++(0:{2*\i*cos(30)})circle[radius=1pt]+(30:1)circle[radius=1pt];
}}

\draw[very thick,red,->](0,0)--node[sloped,below]{$y=6$}(iso cs:0,4,0);
\draw[very thick,blue,->](iso cs:0,4,0)-- node[sloped,above]{$x=2$}++(iso cs:2,0,0);
\draw[very thick,red,->](iso cs:2,4,0)-- node[sloped,below]{$z=3$}++(iso cs:0,0,3);

% Arrows showing the newest coordinate system "iso"
\draw [blue,thick,->](0,4)--node[below]{x}++(iso cs:1,0,0);
\draw [red,thick,->](0,4)--node[left]{y}++(iso cs:0,1,0);
\draw [violet,thick,->](0,4)--node[left]{z}++(iso cs:0,0,1);
\node[below,align=center,draw,fill=white] at (iso cs:0,1,2.7){New \textbf{iso} \\ coordinate system};

\begin{scope}[shift={(iso cs:2,4,3)}]
\draw[blue,thick] (iso cs:0,0,0)--++ (iso cs:3,0,0)
--++ (iso cs:0,3,0)
--++ (iso cs:0,0,3)
--++ (iso cs:-3,0,0)
--++ (iso cs:0,-3,0)
--++(iso cs:0,0,-3)
(0,3)--++(iso cs:3,0,0)--+(0,-3)
(iso cs:0,3,0)--+(iso cs:0,3,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Update Addition of another coordinate system with a vertical key `z` (at Tobi's request)

Its disadvantage is to be more verbose since you have to write 3 coordinates instead of 2.

With keyvals since here the keys are defined with `keyval` package, we can define default values and write for example `(trio cs:x,y=2,z)` instead of `(trio cs:x=0,y=2,z=0)`.
Here, the keys have default values, that is to say that if no value is given, they are worth the default value.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\define@key{triangularokeys}{x}[0]{\def\myx{#1}}
\define@key{triangularokeys}{y}[0]{\def\myy{#1}}
\define@key{triangularokeys}{z}[0]{\def\myz{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{triangularo}%
{%
\setkeys{triangularokeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointxyz{0}{\myz}{0}}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolarxy{-30}{\myx}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{30}{\myy}}
}
}
\makeatother
\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{trio}{triangularo}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[]}]

\newcommand{\nbx}{11}%<--number of point on one row
\newcommand{\nby}{9}%<-- number of point on one column


\foreach \j in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nby-1} {
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nbx-1} 
  {\fill[black](90:\j)++(0:{2*\i*cos(30)})circle[radius=1pt]+(30:1)circle[radius=1pt];
}}

\draw[very thick,red,->](0,0)--node[sloped,below]{$y=6$}(trio cs:x=0,y=4,z=0);
\draw[very thick,red,->](trio cs:x,y=4,z)-- node[sloped,above]{$x=2$}++(trio cs:x=2,y,z);
\draw[very thick,red,->](trio cs:x=2,y=4,z)-- node[sloped,below]{$z=3$}++(trio cs:x,y,z=3);


% Arrows showing the newest coordinate system "trio"
\draw [blue,thick,->](0,4)--node[below]{x}++(trio cs:x=1,y,z);
\draw [red,thick,->](0,4)--node[left]{y}++(trio cs:x,y=1,z);
\draw [violet,thick,->](0,4)--node[left]{z}++(trio cs:x,y,z=1);
\node[below,align=center] at (trio cs:x,y=1,z=3){New trio \\ coordinate system};

\begin{scope}[shift={(trio cs:x=2,y=4,z=3)}]
\draw[blue,thick] (trio cs:x,y,z)--++ (trio cs:x=3,y,z)
--++ (trio cs:x,y=3,z)
--++ (trio cs:x,y,z=3)
--++ (trio cs:x=-3,y,z)
--++ (trio cs:x,y=-3,z)
--++(trio cs:x,y,z=-3)
(0,3)--++(trio cs:x=3,y,z)--+(0,-3)
(trio cs:x,y=3,z)--+(trio cs:x,y=3,z);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### First answer With a coordinate system called `tri` with the `x` and `y` keys.

[image: screenshot]

In addition to the Cartesian coordinates, I have defined a new coordinate system that makes it *"simpler"* to draw figures on this grid.
It is called `triangular` and its alias is `tri`.

For example, the first red arrow is drawn like this:

```
\draw[very thick,red,->](0,0)--(tri cs:x=0,y=7);
```

The second arrow is defined as follows:

```
\draw[very thick,red,->](tri cs:x=0,y=7)--++(tri cs:x=2,y=0);
```

You'll notice that **you can mix the two coordinate systems** in the **same path** and use the relative coordinate.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% new coordinate system called triangular 
\makeatletter
\define@key{triangularkeys}{x}{\def\myx{#1}}
\define@key{triangularkeys}{y}{\def\myy{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{triangular}%
{%
\setkeys{triangularkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolarxy{-30}{\myx}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{30}{\myy}}
}
\makeatother
% end of new coordinate system 

\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{tri}{triangular}%<-- define the alias tri for triangular
   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[]}]

\newcommand{\nbx}{11}%<--number of dots in a single row
\newcommand{\nby}{9}%<-- number of dots in a single column

% Drawing of the isometric grid
\foreach \j in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nby-1} {
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\the\numexpr\nbx-1} 
  {\fill[black](90:\j)++(0:{2*\i*cos(30)})circle[radius=1pt]+(30:1)circle[radius=1pt];
}}

% The following code below shows how to draw on this grid

% Arrows showing the new coordinate system
\draw [blue,thick,->](0,4)--node[below]{x}++(tri cs:x=1,y=0);
\draw [red,thick,->](0,4)--node[left]{y}++(tri cs:x=0,y=1);

% Big red arrow going from the bottom left to the perspective cube
\draw[very thick,red,->](0,0)--node[sloped,below]{$y=7$}(tri cs:x=0,y=7);
\draw[very thick,red,->](tri cs:x=0,y=7)-- node[sloped,above]{$x=2$}++(tri cs:x=2,y=0);

% Cube perspective drawing
\begin{scope}[shift={(tri cs:x=2,y=7)}]
\draw (tri cs:x=0,y=0)circle(3pt)--++ (tri cs:x=3,y=0)
--++ (tri cs:x=0,y=3)
--++ (0,3)
--++ (tri cs:x=-3,y=0)
--++ (tri cs:x=0,y=-3)
--++(0,-3)
(0,3)--++(tri cs:x=3,y=0)--+(0,-3)
(tri cs:x=0,y=3)--+(tri cs:x=0,y=3);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s a nice solution, but shouldn’t there be also a `z` key?!

Comment: Why not, but I'm not sure what use would be made of it? What's your idea about that?

Comment: It could be used for al lines that go straight upwards. As the isometric view is a projection of 3D in 2D all three axis should be available. I’d say …

Comment: @Tobi I just finished it, but its disadvantage is that it is more verbose since you now have to write 3 coordinates instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have the z part optional? I don’t know the coordinate system of TikZ well enough.

Comment: @Tobi I'm asking myself the same question as you and I'm trying to do it. With `keyvals` since here the keys are defined with `keyval`package, we can define **default** values and write for example `(trio cs:x,y=2,z)` instead of `(trio cs:x=0,y=2,z=0)`. 
Here, the keys have `default` values, that is to say that if **no value** is given, they are worth the default value. I already add this to the solution.

Comment: @Tobi It would be more interesting to give an initial value to the keys in order to write `(trio cs:y=2)` `x` and `z` being then equal to `0`. But here, you have to use the `pgfkeys` package and it is hard to understand. I dive into it and do my best. But I don't guarantee anything.

Comment: Don’t invest too much time. It was just a thought. Better wait what the OP says ;-)

Comment: @Tobi That's it, I did it! Phew!

Comment: Well done. Good job! Maybe this should became part of TikZ ;-)

Comment: Hi, why did you disappear? A cordial greeting from Sicily.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your concern, I have a lot of work at the moment and I don't have time to invest in the forum. I hope you are well. :-)

Comment: @AndréC With extreme sincerity I always think of you even as a professor. Right now I'm crying...but it will pass...I always wish you the best and serenity for you and the people you love.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am sorry that you are grieving. I hope that you will get through this ordeal, whatever it is.

Comment: @AndréC I thank you and always wish you every well for all your future days.

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun, a pure PostScript solution for making 1-cm-scale isometric dotted paper. Can be directly sent to a PostScript printer.

Use `ps2pdf` if you need a PDF; but it is much bigger [38 kB] than the PS [242 B]. (The PS code was somewhat optimized for size, though not too aggressively in order not to sacrifice legibility.)

`isometricdottedA4.ps`:

```
%! 
<</PageSize [595 842]>> setpagedevice 
/cm {28.346457 mul} def 
[.866 .5 -.866 .5 595 2 div 842 41 cm sub 2 div] concat 
0 1 41 { cm 
 0 1 41 { cm 1 index exch moveto 
  gsave initmatrix currentpoint 2 0 360 arc fill grestore 
 } for pop 
} for
```

The following version can be used for both, **A4** and **Letter**, formats. Just replace `false` with `true` in the 2nd line for Letter paper. Dots still spaced by 1 cm.

`isometricdottedA4orLetter.ps`:

```
%! 
/letter false def % replace with `true' for Letter paper 
letter {/width 612 def /height 792 def} {/width 595 def /height 842 def} ifelse 
<</PageSize [width height]>> setpagedevice 
/cm2bp {28.346457 mul} def % conversion 
/dots height width 60 sin 60 cos div div add 1 cm2bp div cvi def % # dots filled rhombus height [cm] 
[30 cos 30 sin 60 sin neg 60 cos width 2 div height dots cm2bp sub 2 div] concat % axes rotated (30°, 60°) & translated 
0 1 dots { cm2bp 
  0 1 dots { cm2bp 1 index exch moveto 
    gsave initmatrix currentpoint 2 0 360 arc fill grestore 
  } for pop 
} for
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It's interesting, but how do you actually print a postscript file from, say, a Windows 10 computer?

Comment: No idea, I can only speak for Linux where printing is centred around the PS format: `lpr isometricdottedA4.ps` (Of course, the default printer must be a PS printer. But most Laser printers in office environments, e. g. HP LaserJets, are.)

Comment: @AndréC : Found this on the web: `COPY file.ps \\servername\printername`. Seems to be the way to print a PS file on a PS network printer on Windows, at the DOS prompt.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
    \multips(0,0)(0,1){11}{%
        \multips(0,0)(1,0){11}{%
            \qdisk(0,0){2pt}\qdisk(.5,.5){2pt}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, fun! hahahaha (fun). :-(

Comment: @user213378: Chishijimotoji.

Comment: This grid is not isometric (triangles are not equilateral).

Comment: @AndréC: A good comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Like this? I see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690566/how-to-create-a-mapping-like-the-following-figure/690569#690569).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690566/how-to-create-a-mapping-like-the-following-figure/690569#690569
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view ,declare function={a=3;b=3;h=3;
        }]
        \path
        foreach \X in {-1,...,5}
        {foreach \Y in {-1,...,5}
            {foreach \Z in {-1,...,3}
                {(\X,\Y,\Z)node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill]{}}}}
        (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
        (a,0,0) coordinate (B)
        (a,b,0) coordinate (C)
        (0,b,0) coordinate (D)
        (0,0,h) coordinate (E)
        (a,0,h) coordinate (F)
        (a,b,h) coordinate (G)
        (0,b,h) coordinate (H)
        ;
        \draw  (E)-- (F) -- (G) -- (H) --cycle 
        (E) -- (A) -- (D) -- (H)
        (A) -- (B) -- (F)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]